# Merging pandas dataframe rows with similar values in more than one columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe like this

| ID | Performed Time | Reported Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 13:05. | 15.02. |
| 121 | 14.05. | 16.10. |
| 101 | 14.20. | 15.02. |

I want to filer rows if the ID and the Reported Time are the same. ie the resultant dataframe should be

| ID | Reported Time |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 15.02. |
| 121 | 16.10. |

I tried using groupby to no avail.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'ID': ['13', '13','23', '24'], 'Reported_time': ['13.22.57', '13.22.57','13.23.44', '13.24.01']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df2=df.groupby(['ID','Reported_time']).nunique()
df2
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. However I have other columns in the dataframe. And the values in those columns are  shown as Boolean in the resultant df. I would want to retain the original values and also retain the original index.

Answer (score 0):

You just need `distinct()`:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, distinct
>>> df = tibble(
...     ID=[101, 121, 101],
...     **{
...         "Performed Time": ["13:05.", "14.05.", "14.20."],
...         "Reported Time": ["15.02.", "16.10.", "15.02."]
...     }
... )
>>> 
>>> df >> distinct(f.ID, f["Reported Time"])
       ID Reported Time
  <int64>      <object>
0     101        15.02.
1     121        16.10.
```

I am the author of [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), the grammar of data manipulation in python, which wraps pandas APIs, and also with modin support now.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[["ID", "Reported Time"]].drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Or `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID', 'Reported Time'])`

Comment: Thanks Emma and scapula. Emma's solution retains the rest of the columns. Thank you.